# Calling the degree $d$ homogeneous component of a graded ring/module in Macaulay2

Tags: commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose $R=F[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(x_1^m,\dots, x_n^m)$ with the standard grading and $F$ is any field. I want to be able to define the $i$th graded component $R_i$ in Macaulay2. Right now, I'm comfortable getting Macaulay2 to tell me many useful things about $R_i$ such as its dimension (as an $F$-vector space) but I've been unsuccessful in defining it as its own object that I'm able to call and manipulate. To be somewhat more explicit, I'd like something with the following flavor:

```
i1: F=GF(7);
i2: R=F[x,y]/(x^49,y^49);
i3: C=R_10;
```

It's unclear to me how to get "R_10" explicitly. I tried

```
i3: B=basis(10,R);
i4: C=image B;
```

but these objects aren't actually the same despite having the same dimension.

Comment: $R_{10}$ does not give you the degree 10 component of $R$. Instead, it gives the 10th generating set of $R$ (in some order). Your i3 will just give you an error as your R is generated by two elements x,y. I suggest you check the outputs without semicolons.

Comment: Macaulay2 does not have any way to handle vector spaces. There is no type for vector spaces. The image in your i4 is the submodule generated by $B$; in this case it is the submodule $R_{\geq 10}$, i.e., $\bigoplus_{i=10}^{\infty} R_i$. Let me ask you, what manipulations/computations were you hoping to carry out in the vector space $R_{10}$? Perhaps there is a way to do it, without necessarily creating a vector space (which Macaulay2 literally can't do).

Comment: @ZachTeitler I have a homogeneous polynomial $h$ of degree $d$ and I want to compute the dimensions of spaces built from the kernels of the maps $\psi_i:R_i\rightarrow R_{i+d}$ given by multiplication by $h$. I say "built from" because I am able to compute the dimension of the kernels themselves, but say I want $\dim(\psi_{i+d}^{-1}(\ker\psi_{i+2d}))$ (or some other space like a sum of the kernel with say, an image of the map in smaller degree), I don't know how to ask for that unless I can explicitly write down $\ker\psi_{i+2d}$, you see?

Comment: For what it's worth, $\psi_{i+d}^{-1}(\ker \psi_{i+2d})$ is the same thing as the kernel of the map given by multiplication by $h^2$, $R_{i+d} \to R_{i+3d}$. If $R = F[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I$ then this kernel is a quotient ideal $I : h^2$, specifically the degree $i+d$ part, $(I:h^2)_{i+d}$. Macaulay2 can handle quotient ideals, and then you can compute dimensions. To sum with an image: that sounds like a sum of ideals, adding a quotient ideal (the kernel) with the ideal generated by $h$ or $h^2$ or whatever. Well... not super clear :-( but I hope it helps.